# Object doesn't support property or method 'preventDefault' in bootstrap.js only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am using the code below to hide the modal "signin" after hiding that modal the "changepassword" modal will display. But the below code causing an issue "Object doesn't support property or method 'preventDefault'" in bootstrap.js only in IE.

Code:

```js
$('#signin').modal('hide');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
$('#ChangePassword').modal('show');
```

Bootstrap.js

```js
Modal.prototype.hide = function (e) {
    if (e) e.preventDefault();
    e = $.Event('hide.bs.modal')
    this.$element.trigger(e)
    if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return
    this.isShown = false
    this.escape()
```

Comment: What version of IE?  Also, can you fix your formatting?

Comment: @Prasy - Check to make sure you aren't running under IE8 emulation mode. `Event.prototype.preventDefault()` has been in IE since version 9, but does not exist in 8.

Comment: @Prasy - I know since you said you are using IE 11, but it can run in IE 8 compatibility mode, which will effectively run things **as if it was IE 8**. Can you verify this in your settings?

Comment: @josh- I checked under the Tools>Compatibility view settings and unchecked the Display Intranet sites in compatibility view option but still having the same issue.. any idea?

Comment: @josh- the documentation mode is Edge(Default) and not running in IE8 mode.